# How to swap from duplicate display to multiple monitor in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, multiple-monitors

Essentially I want to make a batch file that will, when executed, swap between two states. the first state would be a duplicate monitor setting, whereas the computer will display the same thing on two screens, while the other setting would be a new monitor, so you could see two different things on the two monitors. I don't know a command that could do this, but it should be possible. I tried looking it up, but could find nothing relevant.

Comment: I'm writing this for my school, that way the teachers can easily swap to show videos or swap back for notes.

Comment: look for nvcpl.dll api manual for how nvidia handles this.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're on Windows 7+

```
DisplaySwitch.exe /clone
```

will duplicate displays.

This will extend displays:

```
DisplaySwitch.exe /extend
```

Hope this helps.

Also you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> if you want a quick shortcut.

Comment: OP did not specify Windows version (it doesn't work on XP) but this should be accepted as answer. I didn't know the Win+P shortcut!

Comment: @cdlvcdlv Support for Windows XP ended April 8, 2014, so I assume he's not asking for an XP solution.

Comment: This indeed works for windows 10 in 2021

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for this using batch-files. However Nvidia drivers do provide a option fore this, it may be possible that other manufacturers have similar documents. I however would not know because all machines I work with have Nvidia cards.

The documentation can be found [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/common/src/NvCpl/docs/NVControlPanel_API.pdf). As per nvidia documentation to set dual monitor mode would be:

```
rundll32.exe setview 1 dualview AA DA
```

And setting both views the same would be:

```
rundll32.exe NvCpl.dll,dtcfg setview 2 clone AA DA
```

Comment: At the school they all have igpu's (old computers) and so I'm not sure how to do this. the reason i want to is because I want the teachers to be able to just simply click an icon on their desktop and then have it swap. hopefully there is a better way to do this. (Teachers at school have no idea how technology works and so teaching them how to swap would be a huge hassle.)